# Angular JS Flying Shopping Cart Animation Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently I'm trying to create an Angular Directive that animates a 'flying shopping cart'.

I have found plenty of solutions with jQuery but none done in a pure Angular Directive. The jQuery flying cart demo that I would like to implement is here...

Original jQuery Flying Cart Codepen:

http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/pen/tEeDn

I am not that experienced with Angular Directives to exactly know how to accomplish this. I have started my own Codepen in hopes of figuring it out but I can't manage to wrap my head around what needs to happen and how.

My current Codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emKoov?editors=101

```
var myApp = angular.module('flyingCartApp', []);

myApp.directive('addToCartButton', function() {

 function link(scope, element, attributes) {
    element.on('click', function(){
    console.log('i was clicked');
    console.log('Image source', attributes.src)
    console.log('Target element', $(attributes.target))
  });
};

return {

  restrict: 'E',
  link: link,
  transclude: true,
  replace: true,
  scope: {},
  template: '<button class="add-to-cart" ng-transclude></button>'
  };
});
```

Comment: Can you post how you would do it without any animation?

Comment: Not sure I follow you Michal. The desired solution will be a aesthetic feel for users. It's to show that something happened after they clicked on a button. It doesn't do anything backend wise. I have a ng-click() function that handles all the backend work of actually adding the item to the database.

Comment: I don't mean the server side code. Presumably you would need to maintain some sort of array of client side model objects of thing that are in the basket, and some code telling the server side when things are added. I suspect it would limit the scope of the question, and also make answers more useful to you, if you show the behaviour you want in terms of these objects without any animation. Then answers can show how you can modify your code to have some animation.

Comment: Ah: I might have misunderstood. I see the jQuery one doesn't show things that are currently in the basket, so you're after something simpler than I thought. Still, would be good to see your controller code with the `ng-click` function that calls the server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is the solution 
[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/shye0000/pen/oXKBgY)

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('flyingCartApp', []);

myApp.directive('addToCartButton', function() {


  function link(scope, element, attributes) {
    element.on('click', function(event){
      var cartElem = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("shopping-cart"));
      console.log(cartElem);
      var offsetTopCart = cartElem.prop('offsetTop');
      var offsetLeftCart = cartElem.prop('offsetLeft');
      var widthCart = cartElem.prop('offsetWidth');
      var heightCart = cartElem.prop('offsetHeight');
      var imgElem = angular.element(event.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1]);
      var parentElem = angular.element(event.target.parentNode.parentNode);
      var offsetLeft = imgElem.prop("offsetLeft");
      var offsetTop = imgElem.prop("offsetTop");
      var imgSrc = imgElem.prop("currentSrc");
      console.log(offsetLeft + ' ' + offsetTop + ' ' + imgSrc);
      var imgClone = angular.element('<img src="' + imgSrc + '"/>');
      imgClone.css({
        'height': '150px',
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': offsetTop + 'px',
        'left': offsetLeft + 'px',
        'opacity': 0.5
      });
      imgClone.addClass('itemaddedanimate');
      parentElem.append(imgClone);
      setTimeout(function () {
        imgClone.css({
          'height': '75px',
          'top': (offsetTopCart+heightCart/2)+'px',
          'left': (offsetLeftCart+widthCart/2)+'px',
          'opacity': 0.5
        });
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(function () {
        imgClone.css({
          'height': 0,
          'opacity': 0.5

        });
        cartElem.addClass('shakeit');
      }, 1000);
      setTimeout(function () {
        cartElem.removeClass('shakeit');
        imgClone.remove();
      }, 1500);
    });
  };


  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    template: '<button class="add-to-cart" ng-transclude></button>'
  };
});
```

css:

```
.shakeit {
  -webkit-animation-name: thumb;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 200ms;
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.itemaddedanimate {
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes thumb {
  0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
  50% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.8); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
}
```